# Issue with localization file while converting from VS2003 application to VS2005

Tags: localization, resources, visual-studio-2003

I have VS2003 project which i converted to VS2005. Everything works however the project has resx files which only opens in VS2003 but not in VS2005. While looking at resource files it looks like the files are missing Designer file in VS2005. Is there anyway to create these designer file in VS2005 easily other than adding new resource file and adding texts in new resource file manually.

I have tons of resource files with bunch of values in there. Just want to save time from retyping all those values again.

Solution: Here is what i did to save time. First imported resx xml content in Excel application. Excel was smart enough to put name and value in separate columns. Copied those name/value pair and pasted in new resource file in Visual Studio. Baam. Done. :)

Comment: Asked 12 years too late.

Comment: @HansPassant will that make a difference i am migrating from 2005 to VS 2015 after that :P